# What is the smallest real perturbation of a Hurwitz matrix where the result is no longer Hurwitz?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, control-theory

What is the smallest real perturbation of a Hurwitz matrix where the result is no longer Hurwitz?  In other words, given a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ where $\min_{i}\textrm{Re}\lambda_i(A) < 0$ what is the smallest matrix $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ in terms of norm where there exists $i$ such that $\textrm{Re}\lambda_i(A+B) \geq 0$?  Here, $\lambda_i(A)$ denotes the $i$-th eigenvalue of $A$.  In case it's not clear, the matrix $A$ is not necessarily symmetric.

Comment: It would help if you could add some detail as to what you're looking for. For example, it's clear that there is no constant perturbation "size" that makes sense as an here, but I suspect that you're looking for an answer in terms of the maximal real part of an eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: I'm looking for a method to construct a minimal perturbation such that the ODE `x'=(A+B)x` is no longer stable when the ODE `x'=Ax` is.  I know that the size of perturbation required to do this can be found by looking at the pseudospectra of `A`, especially when `A` is non-normal, but I'm looking for a concrete way to construct this matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one reasonable bound that answers the question that I suspect you're trying to ask. As a measure for the "size" of a perturbation, I will use the spectral norm (i.e. maximal singular value). The upper bound I give is in terms of $\alpha$, the absolute value of the largest real part among the eigenvalues of $A$, and $\|A\|$, the spectral norm of $A$.

---

From Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis* Theorem VIII.1, we have the following bound on the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) between the spectral sets $\sigma(A)$ and $\sigma(A + B)$:
$$
h(\sigma(A),\sigma(A + B)) \leq (\|A\| + \|A + B\|)^{1-1/n} \|B\|^{1/n}
$$
Where $\|M\|$ denotes the spectral norm of $M$. Let $\epsilon = \|B\|$.
With the triangle inequality, this can be simplified to the slightly weaker bound
$$
h(\sigma(A),\sigma(A + B)) \leq (2\|A\| + \|B\|)^{1-1/n} \|B\|^{1/n} 
\\ = (2\|A\| + \epsilon)^{1-1/n} \cdot \epsilon^{1/n} 
$$
Now, suppose that the maximal real part among the eigenvalues of $A$ is given by $-\alpha$ where $\alpha>0$. In order for $A + B$ fails to be Hurwitz, then it has an positive eigenvalue (i.e. an eigenvalue with positive real part), and the distance between this positive eigenvalue and any of the eigenvalues of $A$ must be at least $\alpha$, which in turn means that the Hausdorff distance $h(\sigma(A),\sigma(A+B))$ has to be at least $\alpha$.

By contrapositive, this means that if $\epsilon$ is chosen so that $h(\sigma(A),\sigma(A + B)) < \alpha$, then we can guarantee that $A + B$ is stable. The right hand side is an increasing function of $\epsilon$, so if we find the solution $\epsilon_0$ to the equation $(2\|A\| + \epsilon)^{1-1/n} \cdot \epsilon^{1/n} = \alpha$, then $A + B$ can only be unstable if $\|B\| \geq \epsilon_0$.

---

We can get a more "concrete" upper bound if that is desired. Suppose that we stipulate that we must have $\epsilon \leq \|A\|$. Then, we can obtain the weaker upper bound on the Hausdorff distance
$$
h(\sigma(A), \sigma(A + B)) \leq (3\|A\|)^{1-1/n} \epsilon^{1/n}.
$$
The solution $\epsilon_1$ to the equation $(3\|A\|)^{1-1/n} \epsilon^{1/n} = \alpha$ is given by
$$
\epsilon_1 = \frac{\alpha^n}{(3\|A\|)^{n-1}} = \alpha \cdot \left(\frac{\alpha}{3\|A\|}\right)^{n-1}.
$$
Thus, if $A + B$ fails to be Hurwitz, then it must be the case that
$$
\|B\| > \min\left\{\|A\|,\frac{\alpha^n}{(3\|A\|)^{n-1}}\right\}.
$$
So, a perturbation $B$ that results in an unstable matrix $A + B$ must be at least this large.